# When Try to upload image localhost http error 500 codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

can anyone help me?
when im trying to upload image using codeigniter file uploading class just like in

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=file%20upload

but i always encounter this error 
[localhost http 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtvdy.png)

please anyone help me.

this is my controller

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('upload_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 1000;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_view', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }}
```

And this is my view upload_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
<?php form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and  upload_success.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Image Upload </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<dl>
    <dt>
        File Name:
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <?php echo $uploadInfo['file_name'];?>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        File Size:
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <?php echo $uploadInfo['file_size'];?>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        File Extension:
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <?php echo $uploadInfo['file_ext'];?>
    </dd>

    <br />
    <p>The Image:</p>
    <img alt="uploaded image" src="<?=base_url(). 'uploads/' . $uploadInfo['file_name'];?>"> 


</dl>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your folder file permission to  chmod -R 777 foldername

Comment: already did that was you said but still encoutered error page  [::1] not working

Comment: Which version you are using??

Comment: there is problem with libraries..download old version 2.2.6 and copy all old libraries to your system->libraries..and once again.

Comment: Use this code after replacing libraires: //Upload folder should be in applications folder $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'uploads/upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$upload=$this->upload->do_upload('fileToUpload');

Comment: thanks you @gulshan for helping me haha.. it was my stupidity, actually it running well, when im updating my xampp, >.<